# Latex Numbering as [Chapter].[Section].[Number of Equation in this section]

Tags: xetex, numbering, chapters

Happy New Year! I write my master thesis in latex and I want for the equations the following format for numbering of the equations:

[Chapter].[Section].[Number of Equation in this section]

For example (1.2.3) is the third equation of section 2 of chapter 1, and (2,2,3) is the third equation of section 2 of chapter 2. Thanks!

My code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{xltxtra} 
\usepackage{xgreek} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9in}]{geometry}
\setmainfont[
    UprightFont = Kerkis,
    ItalicFont = KerkisItalics,
    SlantedFont = KerkisItalics,
    BoldFont = Kerkisb,
    BoldItalicFont = Kerkisbi,
    BoldSlantedFont = Kerkisbi,
    SmallCapsFont = KerkisSmallCaps]
    {Kerkis}
\newcommand{\rp}{\mathbb{RP}}
\newcommand{\eq}{\begin{equation}
\end{equation}}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\usepackage[]{mcode}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{theorem}{\theorembodyfont{\rmfamily}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Θεώρημα}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\newtheorem{prop}{Πρόταση}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Λήμμα}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Ορισμός}
\newenvironment{proof}{\paragraph{Απόδειξη}}{\hfill$\square$}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\cfoot{\thepage}
 \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
\usepackage{pst-plot} 
 \usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftex,colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue}
\usepackage{hypcap}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1 of chapter 1}
\begin{equation}
a^2=b^2+c^2
\end{equation}
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\section{Section 1 of chapter 1}
\begin{equation}
a^2=b^2+c^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: \usepackage{chngcntr} and `\counterwithin{equation}{section}` (all in the preamble) should work, assuming that `\thesection` makes use of `\thechapter` (and it is something like a `book` or `memoir` etc. document class)

Comment: Please provide a working document! I assume that `\thesection` does not call `\thechapter`

Comment: Oh my, your thesis preamble is a mess :-( Why are you loading the outdated `epsfig` and the package `mcode` twice? But the main cause you don't see (and what I suspected the right cause) `1.2.3` is the command `\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}`

Comment: Since you changed `\thesection` `\counterwithin{equation}{section}` will still work, but the format is not changed. Use `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter.\thesection.\arabic{equation}}` for example

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue could be solved in comments